# How to input data from arduino serial monitor to html file?

Tags: html, python-3.x, arduino

I am using dht22 sensor and arduino uno. I am able to get the output of the serial reading and I have communicated it with python through pyserial. So now, my sensor data are appearing on python. I have also created an HTML gui of a thermometer which displays random data. NOW THE PROBLEM IS, I CAN'T FIGURE OUT HOW TO COMMUNICATE MY PYTHON TO THE HTML FILE. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to security reasons with browsers, this is supposedly impossible without any frameworks... But try flask as mentioned above, should get your project up and going!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a service which will be hosting your html page.

There are tons of different frameworks you can use to do that, like Flask, Twisted, Bottle and Django.

I recommend you to go with Flask, with him you can dynamically change values ​​inside html pages, because the html page is being hosted by him.

Flask has a pretty good getting started documentation, [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/)

May the force be with you now.